# ElementTree XPath Expression

Tags: python, elementtree

This is my XML File Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtensionv2.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd">

  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Running">
      <Id>2012-11-17T16:41:52Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2012-11-17T16:41:52Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>473.6400000</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>1600.0000000</DistanceMeters>
      </Lap>
    </Activity>
  </Activities>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

I want to select all the Lap nodes by using Elemtenttree in Python:

```
tree = ET.parse(fileName)
elem = tree.getroot()

for ele in elem.findall('.//Lap'):
    print ele
```

But the code above does not work..

Does anyone has an idea how to select the Lap nodes?

Comment: "does not work" is not a proper problem description. What results do you get, if anything, or is there an error?

Comment: I renamed your closing tag to `</TrainingCenterDatabase>` (removed the `s`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the namespace:

```
>>> tree.findall('.//{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2}Lap')
[<Element '{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2}Lap' at 0x4698f90>]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just printed the tag names and saw the namespace.. Do I always have to specify the namespace, or is there an option to use the  tag without a namespace?

Comment: @user1451130 Check out http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm - kudos to Martijn Pieters for that though...